# assert failed: asus.verify_modem

Tags: adb, lineageos

Following the procedure for [LineageOS installation](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/X01BD/install) after rebooting on recovery and using:

```
adb sideload lineage-18.1-20220228-nightly-X01BD-signed.zip
```

I get:

```
--Wiping data...
Formatting /data...
Formatting /cache...
Data wipe complete.
Enabled ADB.

Now send the package you want to appply
to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
Supported API: 3
Finding update package...
Verifying update package...
Updating package verification took 798.3 s (result 0).
Installing update...
Checking for MODEM build time-stamp 2019-09-03 16:24:00
assert failed: asus.verify_modem("2019-09-03 16:24:00") == "1"
E:Error in /sideload/package.zip (status 1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the updater script check for the current firmware build. Googling `asus.verify_modem` returned a few results ([XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-11-user-build-signed-lineage-18-1-x00td-asus-zenfone-max-pro-m1.4260585/post-85167291), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/nfoonn/problem_with_upgrading_on_x00td_from_160_to_181/)) mentioning that this usually happened if you skip some Android versions and that you need to flash the official firmware first to upgrade them before flashing the ROM.

Comment: adb sideload gives "Signature verification failed" for the ROM

Comment: Your device does not fulfill installation requirements. as @AndrewT. already stated official firmware up-/[downgrade](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042349) is required: *"Error: This package requires firmware version 16.2017.1908.070 or newer. Please upgrade firmware and retry!"* - try Version [MaxProM2_downgrade_to_9](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/ZenFone%20Max%20Pro%20%28M2%29%28ZB631KL%29/HelpDesk_BIOS)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround that might be useful. It worked with me using the Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1. I was having the exact same error using the latest Lineage version `lineage-19.1-20221115-nightly-X00TD-signed.zip`. This phone didn't receive updates since 2018, which seems the reason for the failure.

So here is how I fixed it:

1. Extract the Lineage zip file:

   ```
   mkdir x
   unzip linage lineage-19.1-20221115-nightly-X00TD-signed.zip -d x
   ```
2. Edit the modem assertion in the `updater-script`:

   ```
   vim x/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
   ```

   Change the line from:

   ```
   assert(asus.verify_modem("2019-11-2512:49:03") == "1");
   ```

   to

   ```
   assert(asus.verify_modem("2019-11-2512:49:03") == "0");
   ```

   *This will bypass the assertion for the modem date. I've also tested the modem connectivity after updating to make sure it will not break. I didn't find any hardware failure. After the bypass, everything is working normally as it should.*
3. Save the file and zip it again:

   ```
   cd x
   zip xoot.zip -r .
   ```
4. Run the sideload again:

   ```
   adb sideload xoot.zip
   ```

   The new file will have a signature fail, and therefore when they are sideloaded, Lineage Recovery will present a screen that says Signature verification failed, this is expected, click Continue.